# Lookup in Association

Tags: associations

I have some issues with the Lookup in Association. My association looks as:

```
asso = <|{"The", "food"} -> 1, {"food", "at"} -> 1, {"at", "snack"} ->
1, {"snack", "is"} -> 1, {"is", "a"} -> 1, {"a", "selection"} -> 
1, {"selection", "of"} -> 1, {"of", "popular"} -> 1, {"popular", "Greek"} -> 
1, {"Greek", "dishes"} -> 1, {"dishes", "The"} -> 1, {"The", "appetizer"} -> 
1, {"appetizer", "tray"} -> 1, {"tray", "is"} -> 1|>
```

I want to find the value of specific key in the asso

```
resKeys = Keys[asso]
resKeys[[1]]
Lookup[bigramUniqe, resKeys[[1]]]
```

But I get the next result:

```
{Missing["KeyAbsent", "The"], Missing["KeyAbsent", "food"]}
```

Comment: That's a specialty when using `List`s or `Integer`s as keys in an `Association`. In order to make it unambigous, one has to wrap with `Key`: like this: `Lookup[asso, Key[resKeys[[1]]]]`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help to me today

Comment: You're welcome. (Will be here also tomorrow ;) )